# Mysql Select distinct records from latest dates only

Tags: mysql, distinct

This is my table structure -

```
TABLE : COURSE_LOG

-----------------------------------------------------
|   ID   |   USERNAME   |  COURSE_ID   |    LDATE   |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   1    |     user1    |      22      | 2013-06-01 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   2    |     user1    |      54      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   3    |     user1    |      22      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   4    |     user2    |      71      | 2013-06-04 |
-----------------------------------------------------
```

I want to pick all of `user1`'s `COURSE_ID` data distinctly (along with it's date). Since date will vary between two same `COURSE_ID` entries, I want to pick the row with the more recent date. I am hoping to get a result like this -

```
-----------------------------
|  COURSE_ID   |    LDATE   |
-----------------------------
|      54      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------
|      22      | 2013-06-03 |
-----------------------------
|      71      | 2013-06-04 |
-----------------------------
```

And I would not want this -

```
-----------------------------    
|      22      | 2013-06-01 |    // THIS SHOULD BE OMITTED FROM RESULT BECAUSE THERE
-----------------------------    // IS ANOTHER RECENT ENTRY WITH THE SAME COURSE_ID
```

I'm using this query -

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COURSE_ID), LDATE FROM COURSE_LOG
WHERE USERNAME = 'user1' 
AND LDATE = (
    SELECT LDATE 
    FROM COURSE_LOG
    WHERE USERNAME = 'user1' 
    ORDER BY LDATE DESC 
    LIMIT 1
)
```

But it only picks one row. How do I correct this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try this query

If you want only for `user1` then use this query:

```
select username, course_id, max(ldate) as date
from tbl 
where username='user1'
group by username, course_id
```

### **[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5ede/3)**

```
| USERNAME | COURSE_ID |       DATE |
-------------------------------------
|    user1 |        22 | 2013-06-03 |
|    user1 |        54 | 2013-06-03 |
```

If you want to find the latest date for all users then use this query

```
select username, course_id, max(ldate) as date
from tbl 
group by username, course_id
```

In this query data of `user2` will also be included

```
| USERNAME | COURSE_ID |       DATE |
-------------------------------------
|    user1 |        22 | 2013-06-03 |
|    user1 |        54 | 2013-06-03 |
|    user2 |        71 | 2013-06-04 |
```

Comment: Worked for me. Excellent answer, complete with demonstrations. Thanks.

Comment: The first query will return an error in MySQL 5.7.5 and up because  ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is on by default and the 'username' column is a nonaggregated column which is not included in the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `MAX`:

```
SELECT  COURSE_ID
    , MAX(LDATE) AS LDATE
    FROM COURSE_LOG
    WHERE USERNAME = 'user1'
    GROUP BY COURSE_ID;
```