# Multiple filter for checkout and unreturned item

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I am doing the check-in check-out system for equipment. And I recorded all the check-in and checkout record in a table called item_ledger. Inside the table, there are itemEIN (number), Description, _outQty (1 for checkout and 0 for check-in), date, time,  username and user id.

Now I want to filter the information for the unreturned item. For example, itemEIN (1,2, 3, 4, and 5) has many check-ins and check out records. And only 2 and 3 are not check-in yet. I  want to get the information for 2 and 3 only.

I tried to filter this

```
SELECT * FROM item_ledger WHERE _outQty = 1 ORDER BY _date_ DESC, _time_ DESC
```

But this only shows all the checkout result. I only have the ideas to filter but I don't know how to write the SQL script. The idea is to filter each itemEIN with _outQty = 1 ORDER BY *date* DESC, *time* DESC. 
Do you have any idea or another solution for me?

Comment: Is this your own design? Having date and time separate rather than as a single datetime field makes this more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Yes, I design it but later I found out that can be combined as DateTime. Now, I only concern about the filtering

Comment: Filtering on the latest DateTime is a lot easier than filtering on the record with the latest date and also the latest time for that date.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to return the records for items that are currently checked out (_outQty = 1). The first half of your SQL statement would work `SELECT * FROM item_ledger WHERE _outQty = 1`

This would return all of the information for the checked out items. If you only want the item # or user_id for those items, replace the '*' after the SELECT statement with the attributes you would like to return.

Comment: No, that won't work. An item is only checked out if the most recent record is checked out.

Comment: But I want to select each item# and _outQty is 1 (Not yet return) in the recent record

Comment: Oh, your question was very unclear. You can try something like this, but Ben was right, it's strange that you have Date and Time as separate attributes.  SELECT 
 i.itemEIN,
 MAX(i.date) as date
FROM item_ledger i
WHERE i._outQty = 1
GROUP BY i.itemEIN

This will at least give you the ids of the items. Reference this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16979136/mysql-select-distinct-records-from-latest-dates-only